# Docker: Echo inputs during installations

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and need to install a file that requires a bunch of inputs during the installation.

In a normal bash script I would ECHO the command to fill in the inputs. How does one mimic that behavior in a dockerfile?

Here is my script:

```
#: Copy CPLEX installer binary from S3.
COPY cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin /setup/



#: Install CPLEX and update .bashrc
RUN chmod +x /setup/cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin 
RUN bash cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin 
RUN echo 2              #: - Press 2 for english 
RUN echo -ne '\n'       #: - Press ENTER to confirm prompt 
RUN echo -ne '\n'       #: - Press ENTER to continue 
RUN echo 1              #: - Press 1 to accept license agreement 
RUN echo -ne '\n'       #: - Press ENTER to confirm prompt 
RUN echo -ne '\n'       #: - Press ENTER to accept default path 
RUN echo -ne '\n'       #: - Press ENTER to install 
RUN echo -ne '\n'       #: - Press ENTER to continue 
RUN echo -ne '\n'       #: - Press ENTER to continue 
RUN echo 2              #: - Press 2/ENTER to say no to product usage data collection 
RUN echo -ne '\n'       #: - Press ENTER to confirm prompt 
RUN echo -ne '\n'       #: - Press ENTER to exit the installer 
RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Optimizer1210/cplex/bin/x86-64_linux' >>~/.bashrc 
RUN source ~/.bashrc
```

This is what runs, but then does not get past this step:

```
Step 9/54 : RUN bash cplex_odee1210.linux-x86-64.bin
 ---> Running in c6404632b1b0
Preparing to install
Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
Unpacking the JRE...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...

Launching installer...

===============================================================================
Choose Locale...
----------------

    1- Deutsch
  ->2- English
    3- Espa?ol
    4- Fran?ais
    5- Portugu?s  (Brasil)

CHOOSE LOCALE BY NUMBER:
```

Do I need to chain together my bash run command? Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Dockerfile, each RUN statement is executed sequentially. As indicated, you can't run an interactive program and will need to pass inputs some other way (if you can't refactor the program, you may be able to use shell redirects to provide the inputs from a file or using a heredoc).